# Yocto QtCore/QtCoremod.sip not found

Tags: python, pyqt5, yocto

I'm currently trying to build a Qt5 image on RPi 3B+ using Yocto. I added `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python3-pyqt5 pyton3-pip python3-dev"` in local.conf and trying to import `PyQt5.Qt PyQt5.QtCore PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets and PyQt5.QtWidgets.`

However, for some reason, I can't import PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets. So I `pip3 install pyqtwebengine` but the thing is it cannot find file "QtCore/QtCoremod.sip".

When I searched for the file, it exists in /usr/share/sip/PyQt5/QtCore/QtCoremod.sip. I cannot tell why it's unable to find the file. Could anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.